# Kivy Label add text without overlapping

Tags: python, text, label, kivy

I am making a simple chat room application, and it is working perfectly other than the fact that when a user enters a long message, it overlaps the other messages in the `ScrollView` like this:

[image: Text overlapping]
This is the code for the label:

```
message_lab = Label(text=text, markup=True, size_hint_y=None)
message_lab.width = self.width
message_lab.text_size = message_lab.width, None
self.chat.add_widget(message_lab)
self.scroller.scroll_to(message_lab)
```

Note(s):

The value of `self.width` is 800

`self.chat` is a `BoxLayout` which is the layout inside the `ScrollView`

`self.scroller` is the `ScrollView`

Any help I receive is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a kv rule and Label subclass, something like:

```
<YourLabel>:
    height: self.texture_size[1]
    text_size: self.width, None
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, but when I try doing this same thing in python code, it doesn't work. Do you know why this is?

Comment: You probably didn't actually do the same thing in the Python code. The kv example here automatically creates a binding so that text_size updates when self.width changes, and height updates when self.texture_size changes. You can do this in Python, but must explicitly make the binding to do the updates.

Comment: This works nicely. Although I prefer doing things in code, and did do the Python binding-version of it - which *almost* works identically. For some reason, when the window is resized, it doesn't notify the Label for update (or something). Although I get the reason for the .kv language, not sure I really like it - there's a lot of magic going on under the hood. :)